# Xamarin.Android add toolbar items in left and right corner

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to add toolbar in my app as below image,
Left bar button, center located app name and right bar button.

[image]

I tried google, but not getting solution. Do any one have idea how to do it in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**activity_mail.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="#1286d9"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Payment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tvActionBarTitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibNofication"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_myIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:padding="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar _toolbar;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        _toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);          
        SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //Below you can set you preferred icon              
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_myIcon);
        _toolbar.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        _toolbar.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        _toolbar.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Icons, margins, styles all you need to set according your requirements. If facing issues update your nugets packages.

output screenshot

[image]

Hope it help you.

Comment: I have create a sample page and apply the same activity_mail.axml code, but I can not see any toolbaar in design preview.

Comment: Are you seeing in design preview or executing app? Try to execute app.

Comment: I am unable to see the design preview, even I tried to run the app, but there is no design while start the activity.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for support @Arvindraja

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the Hamburger menu, you will have to check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout/)

Once your Hamburger Menu is ready to check your main page and in your main page you will have a support toolbar in that support toolbar which pretty much works like your ViewGroup do something like :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
 android:background="#33B86C"  
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"  
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also check here to see how to work with a [toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/toolbar-compatibility) in xamarin android which includes adding toolbar items which you see on the top right of your image.

Goodluck!

Revert in case of queries.